# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array when decoding a base64 string to image in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I converted a bitmap to base 64 string in android and passed to my dotnet web service. When i try to decode the base 64 string to image i get the "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array." error.Here is my code to which i used for conversion

```
strimgformat = UserId + strTimeFormat + ".jpg";
string CroppedImagePath = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Photos"] + strimgformat);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(bmp)))
                {
                    using (Bitmap bm2 = new Bitmap(ms))
                    {
                        bm2.Save(CroppedImagePath);
                    }
```

Here is the encoded string from android

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCACHAG4DASIA
AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA
AAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3
ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm   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```

Comment: And where is the decode - source code ?

Comment: using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(bmp)))
                {
                    using (Bitmap bm2 = new Bitmap(ms))  
                    {
                        bm2.Save(CroppedImagePath);
                    }   where bmp conatins the base64 string. i already mentioned here

Comment: Where is the `bmp` there ? (on `Convert.FromBase64String(bmp)`

Comment: i already mentioned above, bmp is "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB........."